# How to get the list of scheduled changes using aws health API

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am trying to list out the scheduled events for health api not sure how to do it. I do not see a way to enable it on console. How can I enable and fetch the details of open scheduled changes.

Comment: Have you tried https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/health.html#Health.Client.describe_event_aggregates ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as if now there is no direct way to enable Health API on AWS console. You have to use CLI or any of the SDK to enable as well as query it.

You have to call **EnableHealthServiceAccessForOrganization** API to enable it for you organisation. You can see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/health/latest/APIReference/API_EnableHealthServiceAccessForOrganization.html) to check how the ways to enable it.

The other thing, to get the list of scheduled events either you can use CLI or SDK. As your question is tagged with Python so I believe you can use Boto3(Python AWS SDK).

You can use [describe_events](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/health.html#Health.Client.describe_events) or [describe_events_for_organization](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/health.html#Health.Client.describe_events_for_organization). You can use [enable_health_service_access_for_organization](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/health.html#Health.Client.enable_health_service_access_for_organization) to enable Health API directly using Boto3.